# Compute the volume of a part of special 4 dimensional ellipsoid.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Please help me to compute the volume of subset of 4 dimensional ellipsoid ($a>b>c>d>0$) $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}+\frac{t^2}{d^2} \leq 1,\ \frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}+\frac{t}{d} > 1 .$$

Note that we have the conditions $a>b>c>d>0$.

Any hints and answers are highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first consider the case $a=b=c=d=1$. We then have a segment of a $4$-dimensional ball of radius $1$. To find the volume of this segment we have to compute the distance of the plane $x+y+z+t=1$ from the origin, which is ${1\over2}$, by Pythagoras' theorem. It follows that the volume in question is
$$V={4\pi\over3}\int_{1/2}^1(1-r^2)^{3/2}\>dr\ .\tag{1}$$
The formula $(1)$ is built analogously to the formula $V=\pi\int_a^b f^2(x)\>dx$ for the volume of a rotational solid created by rotating a graph $y=f(x)$ $\>(a\leq x\leq b)$  around the $x$-axis in $3$-space.

Multiply this with $abcd$ in order to obtain the final result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate how you got expression for $V$? Is it result of some elaborate computation or you got it directly from  some geometric ideas?